# Jackson JsonParseExceptionMapper and JsonMappingExceptionMapper shadows custom mapper

Tags: java, spring-boot, jersey

My project uses Spring Boot + Jersey 2.

I created custom Jackson mapper for JsonParseException, but it didn't get called, standard Jackson JsonParseExceptionMapper used instead.

My custom mapper:

```
 package com.rmn.gfc.common.providers;
 import ...

 @Provider
 public class JsonParseExceptionHandler implements ExceptionMapper<JsonParseException> { 
    @Override
    public Response toResponse(JsonParseException exception) {
        return Response
                .status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST)
                //  entity ...
                .build();
    }
}
```

I register my mapper like this:

```
@Component
public class OrderServiceResourceConfig extends ResourceConfig {
    public OrderServiceResourceConfig() {
        packages("com.rmn.gfc.common.providers");
    }
}
```

I am sure that mapper registration is fine because other custom mappers from this package is working, but one for JsonParseException is shadowed by Jersey standard JsonParseExceptionMapper.

How could I override standard Jackson JsonParseExceptionMapper with my implementation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found solution that is fine for me.
Use `javax.annotation.Priority` on your custom mapper to make it override Jackson default mapper, e.g.:

```
@Provider
@Priority(1)
public class JsonParseExceptionHandler implements ExceptionMapper<JsonParseException> {
    // ...
}
```

OR , if you register JAX-RS components via ResourceConfig, you can specify priority like this:

```
public class MyResourceConfig extends ResourceConfig {
    public MyResourceConfig() {
        register(JsonMappingExceptionHandler.class, 1);
        register(JsonParseExceptionHandler.class, 1);
        // ...
    }
}
```

The lower number the highest priority.
`javax.ws.rs.Priorities` has some predefined constants for priorities.

Comment: It's a fancy solution!

Comment: Which version of jersey ?

Comment: @Brice Jersey 2.x

Comment: yes but 2.21, 2.22, ... ? I don't see any documentation on Jersey on that, and as far as I know this isn't there yet, see [jersey/jersey#2994](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/issues/2994)

Comment: I have jackson-core v. 2.8.6

Comment: Adding the Priotiry(1) is not working for me. The only solution is to add the JacksonJaxbJsonProvider.class in the jersey config. Why priority is not working in my case? i bet I'm missing something

Comment: We know that adding JacksonJaxbJsonProvider can have some side effect? It's safe to add it?

Answer (score 10):

### You can blame the `JacksonFeature`

[`JacksonFeature`](https://jersey.github.io/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/jackson/JacksonFeature.html) registers default exception mappers for Jackson exceptions if the [`JacksonJaxbJsonProvider`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-jaxrs-providers/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/jaxrs/json/JacksonJaxbJsonProvider.html) is not registered. And that's exactly what you don't want.

See the relevant parts of the [source code](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/media/json-jackson/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/jackson/JacksonFeature.java):

> ```
> // Register Jackson.
> if (!config.isRegistered(JacksonJaxbJsonProvider.class)) {
>     // add the default Jackson exception mappers
>     context.register(JsonParseExceptionMapper.class);
>     context.register(JsonMappingExceptionMapper.class);
>     ...
> }
> ```

### Spring Boot registers the `JacksonFeature`

The Spring Boot's [`JerseyAutoConfiguration`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jersey/JerseyAutoConfiguration.html) class will register the [`JacksonFeature`](https://jersey.github.io/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/jackson/JacksonFeature.html) if it's on the classpath. See the relevant parts of the [source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jersey/JerseyAutoConfiguration.java):

> ```
> @ConditionalOnClass(JacksonFeature.class)
> @ConditionalOnSingleCandidate(ObjectMapper.class)
> @Configuration
> static class JacksonResourceConfigCustomizer {
>
>     ...
>
>     @Bean
>     public ResourceConfigCustomizer resourceConfigCustomizer(
>             final ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
>         addJaxbAnnotationIntrospectorIfPresent(objectMapper);
>         return (ResourceConfig config) -> {
>             config.register(JacksonFeature.class);
>             config.register(new ObjectMapperContextResolver(objectMapper),
>                     ContextResolver.class);
>         };
>     }
>
>     ...
> }
> ```

### Workaround

As a workaround, you can register the [`JacksonJaxbJsonProvider`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-jaxrs-providers/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/jaxrs/json/JacksonJaxbJsonProvider.html) and then register your custom exception mappers (or just annotate them with [`@Provider`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/Provider.html) to get automatically discovered by Jersey):

```java
@Component
public class OrderServiceResourceConfig extends ResourceConfig {

    public OrderServiceResourceConfig() {
        packages("com.rmn.gfc.common.providers");
        register(JacksonJaxbJsonProvider.class);
        // Register other providers
    }
}
```

See what the documentation says about [`JacksonJaxbJsonProvider`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-jaxrs-providers/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/jaxrs/json/JacksonJaxbJsonProvider.html):

> JSON content type provider automatically configured to use both Jackson and JAXB annotations (in that order of priority). Otherwise functionally same as `JacksonJsonProvider`.

### Alternative solution

Alternatively you can get rid of the [`jersey-media-json-jackson`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.media/jersey-media-json-jackson) artifact and use [`jackson-jaxrs-json-provider`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider) instead. With this, you will get rid of [`JacksonFeature`](https://jersey.github.io/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/jackson/JacksonFeature.html) and then you can register your own exception mappers.

It was mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44315010/1426227).

### What seems to be the *correct* solution

See the following quote from the [JAX-RS 2.1 specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jaxrs-2_1-final-eval-spec/jaxrs-2_1-final-spec.pdf):

> **4.1.3 Priorities**
>
> Application-supplied providers enable developers to extend and customize the JAX-RS runtime. Therefore, an application-supplied provider MUST always be preferred over a pre-packaged one if a single one is required.
>
> Application-supplied providers may be annotated with `@Priority`. If two or more providers are candidates for a certain task, the one with the highest priority is chosen: the highest priority is defined to be the one
>   with the *lowest* value in this case. That is, `@Priority(1)` is higher than `@Priority(10)`. If two or more providers are eligible and have identical priorities, one is chosen in an implementation dependent manner.
>
> The default priority for all application-supplied providers is `javax.ws.rs.Priorities.USER`. The general rule about priorities is different for filters and interceptors since these providers are collected
>   into chains.

As pointed in Kysil Ivan's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45482110/1426227), write your own exception mapper and give it a high priority, such as `1`. If you use auto discovery, just annotate it with [`@Provider`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/Provider.html) and [`@Priority`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/annotation/Priority.html).

```java
@Provider
@Priority(1)
public class JsonParseExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<JsonParseException> {
    ...
}
```

If you manually register your provider, you can [give your provider a binding priority](https://jersey.github.io/apidocs/2.26/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ResourceConfig.html#register-java.lang.Class-int-):

```java
@ApplicationPath("/")
public class MyResourceConfig extends ResourceConfig {

    public MyResourceConfig() {
        register(JsonParseExceptionMapper.class, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure that registering JacksonJaxbJsonProvider is appropriate workaround for me. I am afraid of side effects. I would like to find more targeted solution, just to register my mapper instead of default. Thanks.

Comment: @KysilIvan Please see my answer again. It has been updated.

Comment: I don't clearly understand consequences of JacksonJaxbJsonProvider registering, don't want to brake something, as application is big and not new.  
  
Thanks for your response, it is informative and helpful, though it is pity that there is no easier way to address this issue.

Comment: @cassiomolin We know that adding JacksonJaxbJsonProvider can have some side effect? It's safe to add it?