# how to map JSON parsing related errors to json response in jersey

Tags: java, rest, error-handling, jersey-2.0, exceptionmapper

I defined a datatype and its API:

```
public class DataType {
    @Column
    private String name;
}

// API is:
public class DataTypeAPI {
    @POST
    @Path("/")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @ManagedAsync
    public void createDataType(
            final DataType dataType,
    ) {
        ...
        asyncResponse.resume(Response.status(Response.Status.CREATED)
                .entity(dataType)
                .build());
    }
}
```

Everything is fine if I posed 
`{
    "name": "xxx"
}`,

but when I posted `{ "name1": "xxx" }`, I got the following `text/plain` response:

```
Unrecognized field "name1" (class com.xxx.datatypes.DataType), not marked as ignorable (1 known properties: "name"])
 at [Source: org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$UnCloseableInputStream@526e34b1; line: 2, column: 15] (through reference chain: com.xxx.datatypes.DataType["name1"])
```

I prefer to convert the above error into JSON response. but event I added the following exception mapper, it is not returning JSON response.

```
@Provider

public class GenericExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<Throwable> {
    public Response toResponse(Throwable ex) {
        System.out.println("GenericExceptionMapper");
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return Response.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                .entity(new ErrorBody(500, ex.getMessage()))
                .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .build();
    }
}
```

Why my above exception mapper cannot catch the jersey parsing error. Could someone explain it to me? Thanks

**UPDATE**

I have two questions:

1, how to make the response to be `application/json` instead of `text/plain`?

2, why my exception mapper did not catch the exception raised and map it to a json response?

**UPDATE**

I added the following mapper:

```
public class JsonMappingExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<JsonMappingException> {
    public Response toResponse(JsonMappingException ex) {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                .entity(new ErrorBody(500, ex.getMessage()))
                .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .build();
    }
}
```

Now, I can get the json response:
`{
    "code": 500,
    "message": "Unrecognized field \"name1\" (class com.xxx.datatypes.DataType), not marked as ignorable (1 known properties: \"name\"])\n at [Source: org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$UnCloseableInputStream@1d8cd12a; line: 2, column: 15] (through reference chain: class com.xxx.datatypes.DataType[\"name1\"])"
}`

I still have two questions:

1, **why my generic exception mapper cannot catch it.**

2, **The json mapping exception mapper cannot map the following exception `Unexpected character ('}' (code 125)): was expecting double-quote to start field name
 at [Source: org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$UnCloseableInputStream@7615743c; line: 3, column: 2]` when `{"name": "xxxx",}`posted (comma , added for testing)**

Answer (score 4):

I met the same issue, and I have solved it. I try to explain your question：

Both `JsonMappingException` and `JsonParseException` extend `JsonProcessingException`. And Jersey has defined `JsonMappingExceptionMapper` for `JsonMappingException` and `JsonParseExceptionMapper` for `JsonParseException`.

1. If you define your own mapper for `JsonProcessingException` (or more wide exception mapper), it cannot catch `JsonMappingException` and `JsonParseException`, because these two exceptions have their own mapper. If they have not, your mapper can catch.
2. If you define your own mapper(say `XxxJsonMappingExceptionMapper` for `JsonMappingException` and  `YyyJsonParseExceptionMapper` for  `JsonParseException`), you may find sometimes you can catch these exceptions, sometimes cannot, it depends your own mapper is working or jersey's mapper is working. **Now, you can add `@Priority(1)`(javax.annotation.Priority) to your mapper to make sure your mapper is working.**  see [Jackson JsonParseExceptionMapper and JsonMappingExceptionMapper shadows custom mapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45478512/jackson-jsonparseexceptionmapper-and-jsonmappingexceptionmapper-shadows-custom-m).

back to your question:

1. Your generic exception mapper cannot catch it becasuse these exceptions has their own exception mapper(`JsonMappingExceptionMapper` and `JsonParseExceptionMapper`, they have a higher priority).
2. You cannot catch the exception may because your own mapper is shadowed by the `JsonParseExceptionMapper`. Try to figure out by adding `@Priority(1)` to your own mapper

Answer (score 1):

> why my generic exception mapper cannot catch it.

Because the Jackson-JAXRS module already comes with [ExceptionMappers for Jackson exceptions](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-jaxrs-providers/tree/master/base/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/jaxrs/base).

> The json mapping exception mapper cannot map the following exception

I didn't test this, but it most likely because it is not a *mapping* exception, but a *parsing* exception. Jackson has both `JsonParseException` and `JsonMappingException`. You can see in the previous link that Jackson comes with an ExceptionMapper for both `JsonMappingException` and `JsonParseException`. You are only overriding the mapper for `JsonMappingException`.

Comment: but after I added my own JsonMappingExceptionMapper, I can get the JSON response. I tried to map `JsonParseException` in mapper, it is not working. so, I am confused.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure about this.

Comment: @BAE  may be the jersey's  `JsonParseExceptionMapper` shadows yours. It's random at the program start. see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Unrecognized field "name1" (class com.xxx.datatypes.DataType), not
>   marked as ignorable (1 known properties: "name"])

If you look at the exception raised, it is quite clear that, your POJO class has property with name `name` not `name1`.

And, you are trying to post your JSON with property name `name1`.

```
{ "name1": "xxx" }
```

And, it wasn't recognized as `name1` wasn't defined instead `name`.

```
public class DataType {
    @Column
    private String name;
}
```

And that is the reason , it works fine for you in other case, when you post JSON as

```
{ "name": "xxx" }
```

Comment: Maybe I did not explain my questions clearly. I already updated my post. Thanks

Comment: @BAE do you have try catch block, I don't see that in your code. If yes, then you need to build JSON response inside your catch block. If you are expecting this will done implicitly. Then you are wrong.

Comment: I think the parsing is done implicitly by jersey. and it did not reach my api codes.

Comment: @BAE Yes, jersey takes care of (de)serialization, depending on your POJO. If you wanted to ignore above exception in all cases. Then you can mark Ignorable.

Answer (score 0):

Im using org.glassfish.jersey-jackson-2.33.
when you register JacksonFeature which is responsible for the default Jackson response with a  "withoutExceptionMappers())".
then if you have some Throwable exception mapper it will be catch instead of the default jackson mapper.
you can also write your JsonParseException mapper if you dont use a Throwable mapper.

```
import org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.JacksonFeature;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature;
import org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScoped;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;

public class JerseyApplication extends ResourceConfig {
    //register(JacksonFeature.class);
    register(JacksonFeature.withoutExceptionMappers());
}
```

---

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException;

@Provider
public class JsonExceptionsMapper implements ExceptionMapper<JsonParseException> {
    @Override
    public Response toResponse(JsonParseException exception) {
         //replace with your custom response
         return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity(exception.getMessage()).type("text/plain").build();
    }
}
```