# How to catch JsonParseException from REST endpoint

Tags: jackson, jersey, jackson-databind

I have an endpoint like this:

```
@POST
public Response update(MyDocument myDocument){}
```

If the request is not valid, my server would get some quite long logs like this:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character....
...
Caused by...
...
Caused by...
```

The exception is hard to be avoided completely, so I am wondering how could I catch the JsonParseException?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Implement an [`ExceptionMapper`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/ext/ExceptionMapper.html) for [`JsonParseException`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonParseException.html). It will allow you to map the given exception to a response. See the example below:

```java
@Provider
public class JsonParseExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<JsonParseException> {

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(JsonParseException exception) {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST)
                       .entity("Cannot parse JSON")
                       .type(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
                       .build();
    }
}
```

And then register it with a *binding priority* in your [`ResourceConfig`](https://jersey.github.io/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ResourceConfig.html) subclass <sup>(see notes)</sup>:

```java
@ApplicationPath("api")
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {

    public JerseyConfig() {
        register(JsonParseExceptionMapper.class, 1);
    }
}
```

If you are not using a [`ResourceConfig`](https://jersey.github.io/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ResourceConfig.html) subclass, you can annotate the [`ExceptionMapper`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/ext/ExceptionMapper.html) with [`@Priority`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/annotation/Priority.html) <sup>(see notes)</sup>:

```java
@Provider
@Priority(1)
public class JsonParseExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<JsonParseException> {
    ...
}
```

---

<sup>**Note 1:** You may also find it helpful to create another [`ExceptionMapper`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/ext/ExceptionMapper.html) for [`JsonMappingException`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonMappingException.html).</sup>

<sup>**Note 2:** Giving a priority to your own [`ExceptionMapper`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/ext/ExceptionMapper.html)s is particularly useful if you have the [`JacksonFeature`](https://jersey.github.io/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/jackson/JacksonFeature.html) registered and you want to *override* the behavior of [`JsonParseExceptionMapper`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-jaxrs-providers/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/jaxrs/base/JsonParseExceptionMapper.html) and [`JsonMappingExceptionMapper`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-jaxrs-providers/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/jaxrs/base/JsonMappingExceptionMapper.html) that come with the [`jackson-jaxrs-json-provider`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-jaxrs-providers) module. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45478604/1426227) for further details.</sup>